# IntentService call sync request error

Tags: android, retrofit2

I running an IntentService. This IntentServiceis running in the background. 
I have Retrofit calls. I do it sync mode.

```
Call<Object> call = apiService.getItem(id);

try {
    Response<Object> response = call.execute();
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        return response.body();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    //...
}
```

Sometimes I got `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` but Why?
It's isn't running on the background thread?

Please give me ideas. Really hard if I need to implement this in async mode.
Thank you!

UPDATE:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
          startTransaction();
    }
```

Comment: where do you call `Response<Object> response = call.execute();` ? inside `startTransaction`?

Comment: Yes, I call there

Comment: post your full code

Comment: Maybe I found the problem. I used Async and Sync calls. Now I changed async calls to sync. This solved the problem. I hope...